# The issue came by catkin_make of Open_manipulator

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, cmake, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During catkin_make of the package of Open_manipulator, came the Problem,

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "robotis_manipulator" with any of the following names:

    robotis_manipulatorConfig.cmake
    robotis_manipulator-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "robotis_manipulator" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "robotis_manipulator_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "robotis_manipulator" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  open_manipulator/open_manipulator_libs/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'robotis_manipulator'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "robotis_manipulator" with any of the following names:

    robotis_manipulatorConfig.cmake
    robotis_manipulator-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "robotis_manipulator" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "robotis_manipulator_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "robotis_manipulator" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  open_manipulator/open_manipulator_libs/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/czm/problem01/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/czm/problem01/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:318: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

I have tried

`$ rosdep install -r --from-path src --ignore-src`

but the issue still come.

And it is also the same problem by catkin_make of Svenzva,

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake:62 (message):
The FindEigen.cmake Module in the cmake_modules package is deprecated.

Please use the FindEigen3.cmake Module provided with Eigen. Change instances of find_package(Eigen) to find_package(Eigen3). Check the FindEigen3.cmake Module for the resulting CMake variable names.

Call Stack (most recent call first): svenzva_ros/svenzva_drivers/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)

-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3) CMake Warning at /home/czm/problem02/build/svenzva_ros/svenzva_drivers/cmake/svenzva_drivers-genmsg.cmake:3 (message): Invoking generate_messages() without having added any message or service file before.

You should either add add_message_files() and/or add_service_files() calls or remove the invocation of generate_messages(). Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:307 (include) svenzva_ros/svenzva_drivers/CMakeLists.txt:30 (generate_messages)

-- svenzva_drivers: 0 messages, 0 services CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message): catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'orocos_kdl' but neither 'orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES' is defined. Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package) svenzva_ros/svenzva_drivers/CMakeLists.txt:36 (catkin_package)

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'svenzva_utils' -- ==> add_subdirectory(svenzva_ros/svenzva_utils) CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mx_msgs" with any of the following names:

mx_msgsConfig.cmake
mx_msgs-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "mx_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "mx_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "mx_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. Call Stack (most recent call first): svenzva_ros/svenzva_utils/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

-- Could not find the required component 'mx_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found. CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package): Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mx_msgs" with any of the following names:

mx_msgsConfig.cmake
mx_msgs-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "mx_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "mx_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "mx_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. Call Stack (most recent call first): svenzva_ros/svenzva_utils/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/czm/problem02/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/czm/problem02/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Makefile:318: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed make: * [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1 Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

i also used

$ rosdep install -r --from-path src --ignore-src

but it make no sense.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310452/the-issue-came-by-catkin_make-of-open_manipulator/) by [iMatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/38964/imatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-12-11**:
Please use the preformatted text button (101010) to format large code snippets and error messages. Also, please do not write answers to questions that are not actually answers. If you'd like to provide more information, please edit your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both of your issues boil down to required packages missing from your workspace. In both instances you seem to think that the `rosdep` command that you issue should somehow mean that you won't have missing packages. However, `rosdep` is only capable of installing packages that have already been released to a package manager (e.g. `apt-get` or `pip`).  My guess is at the top of your `rosdep` command you actually had errors related along the lines of `Cannot locate rosdep definition for [robotis_manipulator]`. You could also check which packages are missing dependencies with `rosdep check --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src`. For any package that cannot be installed automatically from a package manager, you'll need to get the source code. Tools like `rosinstall` and `rosinstall_generator` can help with this, but if the package developer hasn't provided you with that infrastructure, you'll have to get the code yourself.

For `open_manipulator` their official [install instructions](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator/#install-ros-packages)  show you a bunch of packages that you'll need to clone into your workspace.

For `svenza_ros`, they do include [a rosinstall file](https://github.com/SvenzvaRobotics/svenzva_ros/blob/master/dependencies.rosinstall) and [instructions for using it](https://github.com/SvenzvaRobotics/svenzva_ros#installing) to ensure you have required, unreleased packages (including `mx_msgs` which is causing your error).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iMatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/38964/imatch/) on 2018-12-12**:
Thank you very much! I have solved this problem by your help~

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-12-12**:
Excellent! Glad that you figured it out.